# maven missing artifact annoying error

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, myeclipse

why is maven always giving me this stupid error ?

```
06/08/12 22.06.39 CEST: Missing artifact javassist:javassist:jar:3.9.0:compile
```

i also tryed to manually add the dependency manually in pom.xml but still getting this  error....
i'm using myeclipse for spring 8.6 this happens sometimes when i add hibernate nature to my project, sometimes without touching nothing , sometimes adding rcp dependencies, ecc ecc

i'm really thinking to just leave this buggy sort of build plugin :|

Comment: spring 8.6? That's bleeding edge.

Comment: http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?name=Recommend_Us&req=Download&version=ME4S

Myeclipse for spring 8.6, not spring framework 8.6 ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing `stupid` about this error.  There is no version `3.9.0` in maven central.  The closest I could see is [3.9.0.GA](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavassist%7Cjavassist%7C3.9.0.GA%7Cjar)